# Php isset() function is not working properly

Tags: php

I have a registration form that user submits. Data is sent using `isset($_POST)` to see if there is anything that was put into form input boxes. If not it is sent to an else, which then sends it to a function that returns the user back to registration form to complete some missing forms. For some reason it is not working properly.

Here is my checking code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { 
  $f_name=$_POST['fname'];
 $l_name=$_POST['lname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $output_form= false;

  if(empty($f_name) && empty($email))
  {
         echo 'please enter all the fields.<br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
   if(empty($f_name) && (! empty($email)) )
     {
         echo 'please enter first name.<br />';
             $output_form = true;
     }
            if((!empty($f_name)) &&    empty($email) )
          {
                 echo 'please enter E-Mail.<br />';
                $output_form = true ;
             }

               if((!empty($f_name)) && (!e     mpty($email)) )
              {
                echo 'success.<br />';
                 $output_form= true;
            }
          }
       else  $output_form = true; 

     if ($output_form)
   {
     ?>

    <table border="0" align=center         bgcolor=pink>
     <tr>
      <FORM NAME="form1"    METHOD="POST" ACTION="<?php echo    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   <td wedth='75' >first name:<INPUT   TYPE="TEXT" VALUE=""   NAME="fname"><br></td><br>
      <td wedth='75' >last name:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" VALUE=""  NAME="lname"><br></td><br>
      <td>e-mail:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="" NAME="email"><br></   td><br>
      <td><INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit1' VALUE='submit'>
   </tr>
  </table> 
    <?php
   }
    ?>
```

Comment: `<INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit1' VALUE='submit'>` != `$_POST['submit']` => `submit1`!=`submit`. You need to change either `submit1` or `submit`

Comment: but VALUE='submit'  then what is the problem

Comment: It is the `name` attribute that you use in `$_POST`, not the `value`. If you want to check the `value`, you would do `if($_POST['submit1'] == 'submit')`

Comment: Oh! Yes now it is working. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the "name" attribute of your HTML button code is "name1" but you're checking for $_POST['name'] instead.

Change your submit button to:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
```

Your if condition will work now.

Answer (score 1):

I tidied up your php:

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ 
        $f_name=$_POST['fname'];
        $l_name=$_POST['lname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $output_form= false;
        if(empty($f_name) && empty($email)){
            echo 'Please enter the fields<br/>';
            $output_form = true;
        } else {
            if(empty($f_name) && (!empty($email))){
                echo("Please enter first name <br/>");
                $output_form = true;
            } else {
                if(!empty($f_name) && (empty($email))){
                echo("Please enter your email");
                $output_form = true;    
                } else {
                    // You wouldnt really need an if statement here considering it went through all the possibilitys but just incase for security reasons Ill go ahead and make it
                    if(!empty($f_name) && (!empty($email))){
                        echo("Success<br/>");   
                    };
                };
            };
        };
?>
```

I also fixed your html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Meta Data and title and other stuff goes here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" align="center" bgcolor="pink">
            <tr>
                <form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"> <!-- Im not sure what you were aiming for here wihh your action statement with your echoing but I left it alone -->
                    <td width="75">First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br/></td>
                    <td width="75">last name: <input type="text"  name="lname"><br/></td>
                    <td width="75">Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit"></input></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When giving answers, it's considered best practice to provide a text explanation of your answer, as well as the code itself - ie what needed changing and why.

Comment: Thanks for that :)